# R: Formattable -Column Will Not Update Based Upon Condition

Tags: r, if-statement, formattable

I run this code to produce the formatted table and I get no error but the condition I have set in place appears to not be working at all. I It looks right? What I am trying to do is for 'mAge' column if the value in that row is > 45.63, then the color should be red. If it is not that color then no change.

```
formattable(data.4)
formattable(data.4, align = c("l", rep("r", NCOL(data.4) - 1)))
formattable(data.4,list(`ICD10Code` = formatter(
"span", style = ~ style(color = "black",font.weight = "bold"))),`mAge` = formatter(
"span", style = ~ ifelse("mAge" > 45.63, style(color = "red", font.weight = "bold"), NA)))
```

Data Sample:

```
ICD10Code mAge Frequency
         50.6         5
  A084   35.0         1
  A609   31.0         1
  A749   38.0         1
  B001   37.0         1
  B079   47.0         1
```

[image]
Clearly, I have something off but I am not sure what as I get no errors.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data for us to work with (`dput(data.4)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is parentheses placement (and removing quotes from mAge in `ifelse`):

```
library(formattable)

formattable(data.4)
formattable(data.4, align = c("l", rep("r", NCOL(data.4) - 1)))
formattable(data.4,list(
  `ICD10Code` = formatter(
    "span", style = ~ style(color = "black", font.weight = "bold")),
  `mAge` = formatter(
    "span", style = ~ ifelse(mAge > 45.63, style(color = "red", font.weight = "bold"), NA))))
```